# zip error: Could not create output file <was replacing the original zip file>

Tags: windows, replace, zip, winscp

I have a Task Scheduler that runs WinSCP.exe that takes the zip file from the Desktop and sends it to Linux box.

I get following error if I try to replace the old zip file with a new one, since I want the data to be updated daily.

```
>pushd C:\Users\Desktop\ct    
>zip -9 -m -r XML.zip zipfolder\*.xml    

zip warning: new zip file left as: zia06608
zip warning: Permission denied
zip error: Could not create output file <was replacing the original zip file>

>popd
```

I cannot even manually delete this zip folder. It says:
The action cannot be completed because the folder is open in WinSCP.exe

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find any running WINSCP process in windows task manager/processes tab ? If yes then end that task & try zipping again.